# error when call CreatePHI() in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

I debug this for two days! cannot find any reasons or infos after search the official documents and google.

Is it bug's of LLVM? help me please.

(LLVM version: 3.7.1)

the error info:

```
Assertion failed: HasHungOffUses && "alloc must have hung off uses", , file I:\GitHub\Def\llvm\lib\IR\User.cpp, line 44
```

the code:

```
Value* ASTIf::codegen(Gen & gen)
{
    // if 
    Value *v_ret(nullptr);
    auto *thefunc = gen.builder.GetInsertBlock()->getParent();

    Value *v_cond = cond->codegen(gen);
    auto *b_then = BasicBlock::Create(gen.context, "then", thefunc);
    auto *b_else = BasicBlock::Create(gen.context, "else", thefunc);
    auto *b_merge = BasicBlock::Create(gen.context, "ifcont", thefunc);

    // 跳转分支
    gen.builder.CreateCondBr(v_cond, b_then, b_else);

    // then block
    gen.builder.SetInsertPoint(b_then);
    Value *v_then = pthen->codegen(gen);
    gen.builder.CreateBr(b_merge);
    b_then = gen.builder.GetInsertBlock();

    // else block
    gen.builder.SetInsertPoint(b_else);
    Value *v_else = pelse ? pelse->codegen(gen) : nullptr;
    gen.builder.CreateBr(b_merge);
    b_else = gen.builder.GetInsertBlock();

    // merge block
    gen.builder.SetInsertPoint(b_merge);
    // if error: HasHungOffUses
    if (canphi) {

        PHINode *phi = gen.builder.CreatePHI(  //////////  error line   /////////
            v_then->getType(), 2, "iftmp");
        phi->addIncoming(v_then, b_then);
        phi->addIncoming(v_else, b_else);
        v_ret = phi;
    }

    return v_ret;
}
```

add call stack for notice of comment:

[see the screenshot of call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odc6I.png)

Comment: I think we need to know what the condition for hitting that assert is? What is the callstack?

Comment: What is `pelse` in your situation? I think it is not a good idea to give `addIncoming` a `nullptr`.

Comment: Looking at the code uses seams robust to me, maybe you have s heap corruption somewhere in your non llvm code.

Answer (score 2):

Please turn off VS's SDL checks (*Configuration Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *General* -> *SDL checks*). 
The assertion checks a bitflag `HasHungOffUses` set by `operator new`, which may be overwritten when SDL is on.

`gen.builder.CreatePHI` calls `User::operator new(size_t Size)`, which assigned `HasHungOffUses` in the memory allocated but not initialize. It should be remain what it is before ctor called.

Code below comes from LLVM svn 266960 (3.9.0 in development)

```
void *User::operator new(size_t Size) {
  // Allocate space for a single Use*
  void *Storage = ::operator new(Size + sizeof(Use *));
  Use **HungOffOperandList = static_cast<Use **>(Storage);
  User *Obj = reinterpret_cast<User *>(HungOffOperandList + 1);
  Obj->NumUserOperands = 0;
  Obj->HasHungOffUses = true;
  Obj->HasDescriptor = false;
  *HungOffOperandList = nullptr;
  return Obj;
}
```

Notice `Obj->HasHungOffUses = true;`

Then it comes to `PHINode`'s ctor

```
explicit PHINode(Type *Ty, unsigned NumReservedValues,
             const Twine &NameStr = "",
             Instruction *InsertBefore = nullptr)
    : Instruction(Ty, Instruction::PHI, nullptr, 0, InsertBefore),
    ReservedSpace(NumReservedValues) {
setName(NameStr);
allocHungoffUses(ReservedSpace);
}
```

and

```
void User::allocHungoffUses(unsigned N, bool IsPhi) {
assert(HasHungOffUses && "alloc must have hung off uses");
static_assert(AlignOf<Use>::Alignment >= AlignOf<Use::UserRef>::Alignment,
              "Alignment is insufficient for 'hung-off-uses' pieces");
static_assert(AlignOf<Use::UserRef>::Alignment >=
              AlignOf<BasicBlock *>::Alignment,
              "Alignment is insufficient for 'hung-off-uses' pieces");
// Allocate the array of Uses, followed by a pointer (with bottom bit set) to
// the User.
size_t size = N * sizeof(Use) + sizeof(Use::UserRef);
if (IsPhi)
    size += N * sizeof(BasicBlock *);
Use *Begin = static_cast<Use*>(::operator new(size));
Use *End = Begin + N;
(void) new(End) Use::UserRef(const_cast<User*>(this), 1);
setOperandList(Use::initTags(Begin, End));

}
```

If sdl is turned on, the memory allocated by op-new seems to be memset to 0 before ctor, which gives `HasHungOffUses` a `false` value, so the assertion fails.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the case: `operator new` sets `HasHungOffUses` flag, but when the flow reaches `Instruction` constructor, the flag is reset to 0 due to `/sdl`.